# Validations with geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I'm trying to figure out where to add errors for validations to a rails 4 app that uses geocoder.

My model looks like this:

```
class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user      
  validates_presence_of :user_id

  geocoded_by :address do |obj, results|
    if geo = results.first
      obj.latitude = geo.latitude
      obj.longitude = geo.longitude
      obj.country = geo.country
      obj.city = geo.city
      obj.postalcode = geo.postal_code
      obj.address = geo.address
    end
  end
  after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?

end
```

I noticed that the `if geo = result.first` conditional only gets executed if the address was found successfully. I'd like to add an error message if nil is being returned. I saw that [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760692/validating-longitude-latitude-with-geocoder-gem) explains that I should be using `before_validation` instead of `after_validation`, but I still don't understand where to add errors so that my view can get re-rendered and a valid geolocation can be input.

Any ideas where I should be putting this information?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set in the model like this example below to validate address the geocode will be called only once when the address changed. In geocoded_by method we set explicitly to write latitude and longitude so than when the address would not be found those columns will be set to nil.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   geocoded_by :address do |object, results|
    if results.present?
     object.latitude = results.first.latitude
     object.longitude = results.first.longitude
    else
     object.latitude = nil
     object.longitude = nil
    end
  end

  before_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?

  validates :address, presence: true
  validates :found_address_presence

  def found_address_presence
    if latitude.blank? || longitude.blank?
      errors.add(:address, "We couldn't find the address")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user      

  before_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?

  validates :user_id, :address, presence: true

  geocoded_by :address do |obj, results|
    if geo = results.first
      obj.latitude = geo.latitude
      obj.longitude = geo.longitude
      obj.country = geo.country
      obj.city = geo.city
      obj.postalcode = geo.postal_code
      obj.address = geo.address
    else
      obj.address = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work because, if the address has not been input in the database yet, the condition `validates :address, presence: true` will always return an error because the address gets generated by geocoder after it makes the API request.

Comment: so the geocoded should make its request BEFORE validation. That's why there is a before_validation in there...